# Spring request matcher issue on JBoss after update to Spring Security 5.8.6

Tags: spring, security, jboss, wildfly

After upgrading from Spring Security 5.8.2 to 5.8.6, I am having an issue with my deployment on JBoss EAP 7.4 (it works fine on embedded Tomcat). I get this error message:

> This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC
> patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use
> requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use
> requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).
>
> This is because there is more than one mappable servlet in your
> servlet context: {org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet=[*.jsp,
> *.jspx], javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet=[/faces/*, *.jsf, *.faces, *.xhtml], org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=[/]}.
>
> For each MvcRequestMatcher, call MvcRequestMatcher#setServletPath to
> indicate the servlet path.

How can I solve the problem? We have only controllers annotated by @Controller and no custom servlets. My security configuration is basically as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class MySecurityConfig
{
    @Bean
    MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc(HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector)
    {
        return new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector);
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity, MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc) throws Exception
    {
       return httpSecurity
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                        auth.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)
                                .permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(
                                        mvc.pattern("/my-public-controller-1/**"),
                                        mvc.pattern("/my-public-controller-2/**"),
                                        mvc.pattern("/my-public-controller-3/**"))
                                .permitAll()
                                .anyRequest()
                                .authenticated())
                .build();
    }
}
```

We use a JBoss default configuration. There is a `jboss-web.xml` and a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`. The last file looks like this:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="com.sun.xml.bind"/>
        </dependencies>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jaxrs"/>
            <subsystem name="logging"/>
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I tried to play around with the request matchers like this, but it did not help.

```
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity, MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc) throws Exception
    {
        return httpSecurity
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                        auth.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)
                                .permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(
                                        mvc.pattern("/my-public-controller-1/**"),
                                        mvc.pattern("/my-public-controller-2/**"),
                                        mvc.pattern("/my-public-controller-3/**"),
                                        antMatcher("/faces/*"))
                                .permitAll()
                                .anyRequest()
                                .authenticated())
                .build();
    }
```

And I tried to exclude Faces from `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`, but this step ruined everything:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="com.sun.xml.bind"/>
        </dependencies>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jaxrs"/>
            <subsystem name="logging"/>
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="main"/>
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I have seen a similar problem described here, but I have not been able to find a working solution from it: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/13568

btw we use the default servlet path, so this suggestion from error message makes no sense to me:

> For each MvcRequestMatcher, call MvcRequestMatcher#setServletPath to
> indicate the servlet path makes

Nevertheless, I tried something similar to this, but that didn't help either:

```
    @Bean
    MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc(HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector)
    {
        return new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector).servletPath("");
    }
```

Comment: Okay, as a temporary solution I switched from Spring Security 5.8.6 to 5.7.10. I hope they can work out a better solution in the near future. There are a lot of complaints about this new matching behavior: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/13568

Answer (score 0):

My SecurityConfig looks like:

```
package com.mycompany.ws.config

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityCustomizer
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain
import org.springframework.security.web.servlet.util.matcher.MvcRequestMatcher
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    fun webSecurityCustomizer(
        introspector: HandlerMappingIntrospector,
    ): WebSecurityCustomizer {
        val mvcMatcherBuilder = MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector)
        return WebSecurityCustomizer { web: WebSecurity ->
            web.ignoring() // Spring Security should completely ignore URLs starting with /resources/ and so forth
                .requestMatchers(
                    mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/resources/**"),
                    mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/static/**"),
                    mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/css/**"),
                    mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/js/**"),
                    mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/img/**"),
                    mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/lib/**"),
                    mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/favicon.ico")
                )
        }
    }

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun securityFilterChain(
        http: HttpSecurity,
    ): SecurityFilterChain {
        return http
            .authorizeHttpRequests { cfg ->
                cfg.anyRequest().permitAll()
            }
            .csrf { it.disable() }
            .cors { it.disable() }
            .formLogin { it.disable() }
            .build()
    }

    companion object {
        val log: Logger = LogManager.getLogger(this::class.java)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are on *Wildfy*. Add *jboss-deployment-structure.xml* file under *web-inf* and you should be good to go.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="logging" />
            <subsystem name="jsf" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Am on *Wildfly 27.0.1* with *Spring boot 3.1* and *JDK 17*.

As per the error message - there are 3 servlets on classpath. *Dispatcher* provided by *Spring Boot* and the other 2 by *Wildfly* for *JSF* & *JSP*.

By adding this file, we are telling the app server that - do not add *JSF* servlets on my apps class path.

The *subsystem* names can be checked in *standalone*.xml file.

[image]

For `org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet=[*.jsp, .jspx]` I commented *jsp-config* in *standalone.xml*

[image]